# Is ephemeral, authenticated, encrypted TLS-PSK ready to use commercially?

Tags: tls, openssl

I have a secure way to get a pre-shared key between my server and all of the clients.

Is there a standard, easily available (e.g. in an OpenSSL release) way to use this to set up TLS-PSK with all of these nice features?

- Confidential
- Authenticated
- Perfect forward secrecy

I see TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA in [RFC 5489](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5489), which *looks* like it checks these boxes. Checking my installation of OpenSSL 1.1.1a (`openssl ciphers -s -psk)` I see `ECDHE-PSK-AES-256-CBC-SHA`.

Is that the right cipher suite to use? Does it actually provide the features I need? Ideally I want to configure OpenSSL on each end to allow just that one cipher suite, and then each end provides the same PSK, and then I have perfect forward secrecy and authentication.

I've only ever done "traditional" TLS with X509 certificates before so I'm a little out of my element.

Comment: 1. You want a GCM ciphe suite, not a CBC one. 2. Even if openssl supports this (I don't know whether it does or doesn't), you'll need server and client software that support this. Unless you're doing custom software anyway, this is prohibitive (if you could have just used nginx and curl and now you can't and must roll your own HTTP server and client...)

Comment: We only need a basic TCP connection, not an HTTP server or anything. We're writing both server and client software, so as long as we find some library that supports the encryption, that's good enough. I understand that GCM is preferred to CBC, but is that a serious security risk? I haven't found any libraries that support ECDHE PKS *and* GCM.

Comment: Not finding library that supports GCM is a bad sign. The CBC cipher suites are not present in TLS 1.3 for a good reason - too difficult to implement securely. I think if you can't get PSK working with openssl 1.1.1 with TLS 1.3, you shouldn't do PSK and switch to something more common like mutual TLS with certs.

Comment: TLS 1.3 PSK has a security issue: https://twitter.com/colmmacc/status/1113432647751979010?s=19